# react app 404 error after clear cache in browser

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404

how can I fix 404 error after clear cache in browser and restart page? I understand that there should be redirect to index.html but how to do this? My .htaccess file is:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /PATH/TO/PROJECT/ROOT/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```